# I want to figure out how to get data from SecureCRT with pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto, secure-crt

I am making pywinauto code that automatically open SecureCRT and read file.

I succeed until opening SecureCRTand running command.

But i can't figure it out how to read txt file.
Because it could not show SecureCRTconsole info. it's just blank.

One way i think is redirecting output to python.

I  want to figure out how to get data from console with python ?

I tried to get tag using print_control_identifiers().

But console is just blank.